# Mantain session between tests using Geb

Tags: grails, geb

I'm testing my application using Geb, and I want to mantain session between tests so I can avoid to log in in every tests (this is annoying when watching the tests in the browser).

Is there a way to mantain the session?

Comment: Open issue http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEB-130

Comment: I would suggest that having to watch the browser log in is not a great reason to maintain session between tests. This is for 2 reasons.

1. Tests should be independent. You lose the ability to run the tests in parallel and tests become dependent on other tests succeeding.

2. Tests should return a pass or fail result. You shouldn't need to watch the test in a browser, only view the report when they are finished.

Just a couple of suggestions...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default Geb test integrations clear all the cookies after every test which means that you loose your web sessions. You can easily change that behaviour by using the [following configuration option](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/configuration.html#auto_clearing_cookies) in your GebConfig.groovy:

```
autoClearCookies = false
```

You can read more about using configuration [here](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/configuration.html).

So yes, it is possible to maintain session between tests.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spock, one option that you can do is to structure your "features" (test methods) in a linear fashion and use the @Stepwise annotation on the class.  This will ensure that the cookies and browser object are not reset/replaced between features/test-methods

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it isnt possible now. My specs start by logging in and finish by logging out.