# maintain the session between different geb specs

Tags: grails, spock, geb

I'm working with grails + geb + spock. Basically I'm creating geb specs for different flows, for example I have a geb spec only for registration, in each spec I use the annotation @StepWise so I can maintain the session between tests in the same spec. But my problem is that I need to maintain the session between different specs (different classes in different files). So for example the spec for registration runs, and after that, I need to test another flow where I need that user created in the prev spec. I think is not a good practice to repeat all the flow to register a user, and also is not good to include in just one spec tests for different flows. Does somebody know if there is something similar to @StepWise but for different specs?

thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could refactor your registration spec into a utility class that performs the registration - you could then call this from your other stepwise specs that need to maintain the session following registration?

Comment: it's a good approach, but anyway I would need to register in any spec, I was thinking if there is something that I need to register once and then keep that state between all the specs.

Comment: Looks like there's a JIRA open for this. There's a workaround you could try that [involves subclassing GebSpec](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEB-130).

Comment: Also another stackoverflow question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575999/mantain-session-between-tests-using-geb)