# Geb session keeping example

Tags: session, webdriver, geb

I am searching for a simplest working example of implementing geb that will keep session.

I read [Mantain session between tests using Geb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575999/mantain-session-between-tests-using-geb) still it is not ready to use example.

Session keeping of logging cookies is practical in most of tests so it should be easy to follow example. If easy solution exist with other webdriver releated technology it could also be interesting to know.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import geb.Configuration
import geb.Browser
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.By

Browser browser = new Browser(driver: new FirefoxDriver())
browser.getConfig().autoClearCookies=false;
browser.getDriver().get("http://mypage.com/login")

browser.getDriver().findElement(By.id("user_login")).sendKeys("admin")
browser.getDriver().findElement(By.name("user_pass")).sendKeys("admin");
browser.getDriver().findElement(By.name("user_pass")).submit();
```

Still I can not connect to browser with autenticated cookie, I has to provide password every time(site use cookies veryfication and in normal browser it is keeped).

Comment: Doesn't putting `autoClearCookies = false` in `GebConfig.groovy` preserve web sessions between test for you?

Comment: I am far from configure it correctly. I understand that I use this config, still it seems that in eclipse not much is found. Eclipse see Browser, but not $ so I guess I need more basic example.